# java authentication on OpenLDAP without OU in base gives invalid credentials

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi, openldap

My scope is to authenticate only with 
**uid=User,dc=ldap,dc=com**.
With this base I get the following error 
*`LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), errorMessage='invalid credentials`')*

I can succesfull authenticate with a Java application to an `OpenLDAP` with the following base: **uid=User,ou=People,dc=ldap,dc=com**. So without writing the multiple organizational units that the user is part of.
I was also able to authenticate on a different environment to ActiveDirectory only with ***uid=User,dc=com*** but not on `OpenLDAP`.

- Is there a setting on `OpenLDAP` that I missed?
- Is there something in `Java` that I can use for workaround?
  I would prefer a solution with `JNDI`.

In java I used `JNDI` and also UnboundID for test. These are the java connection settings:

```java
    //JNDI Connection
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=User,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    //UnboundID connection
    LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(ip, 389, "dc=ldap,dc=com", pswrd);
```

File **ldap.conf**:

```
BASE dc=ldap,dc=com
```

File **slapd.conf**:

```
suffix      "dc=ldap,dc=com";
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=ldap,dc=com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need a Fully Qualified Distinguished name. (Except for a few [exceptions with Microsoft Active Directory](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Ambiguous%20Name%20Resolution)).

You are always better off to perform a search for the user ([Some examples](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/91c2df9b5481b30e5ca213a7baa0ce7e0a04752c/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicAdminSearchBind.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) )

-jim

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a setting on OpenLDAP that I missed?

No.

> Is there something in Java that I can use for workaround?

No. You have to provide the full DN.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.
Is this only for OpenLDAP? Why is there a difference between ActiveDirectory and OpenLDAP?
When I connected to the ActiveDirectory I used port 3268 that connects me directly to the ldap.

Comment: It is for any LDAP-compliant implementation. AD isn't entirely LDAP-compliant. I don't see what the port number has to do with it.